# Storyboard with table RTE missing tableview in NIB

Tags: iphone, ios5, uistoryboard

I just updated to the latest XCode and IOS 5... Things I used to do don't seem to work now.

On the "XIB" on the storyboard I have a UIViewController. Under that I put a View and under that I put a UITableView.

I right click and attach the datasource and delegate to the top level UITableViewController mentioned above.  On the "old" way with just a XIB file I used to attach these to FILES OWNER.

Then I make an IBOutlet named myTable and attach the table to that outlet.

Prior to this version of XCode that is all I needed to do and then I was able to do the code.

Now even though I do all of above when the app starts it says the XIB is missing the UITableView.

So I started over and took out the UIView.  So now I have a UIViewController and the UITableView under that. And now the app works.  It seems as though references I add do not matter using this simple nib. This would be good but I need to add other object at the UIView.

Hope this wasnt too confusing! What I need to know is when I create the nib on the storyboard, then add the view and then the table, what references or outlets or whatever it wants so the app will run?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this two tutorials on storyboards:
[Storyboards tutorial part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1)
[Storyboards tutorial part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2)

Comment: Read both of these as well a few more. I think people are using XIB nibs for the things that dont yet work in the SB,  I didnt find reference to a table under a view that was tied into the app. Just stick with the NIBS I guess

Comment: I've been recently switching from nibs to storyboard. I think the best approach is to use just one of these - a pure storyboard or pure xib/nib based app - otherwise it quickly gets confusing and bugs arise.

Comment: I think the ket sentence the the tutorials above said something like the the storyboard was new and does not have the full functionality of the XIB, yet.  It still seems odd to me that I can not have the table on top of a view and have it referenced so the app can find it. It still works on the XIB, so this new app I am writing I guess I will go with nibs only.  oh well...